# Remove single line of code in multi-line textbox

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to code a button that when clicked removes the last line of text in a multi-line textbox. It works to remove the lastline of text if there are two lines of text in the textbox, but if there is only one line in the textbox it results in an error.

Eg.
Adding this to the box:

```
line of text 1
line of text 2
```

And using the remove button twice, I can remove both of the lines of text

But if I do something like this:
Add this line to the textbox:

```
line of text 1
```

Then try to remove it, it errors.

I know it errors because I use this twice

```
            ' remove box text
        QuoteHistoryBox.Text = QuoteHistoryBox.Text.Remove(QuoteHistoryBox.Text.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine))
        QuoteHistoryBox.Text = QuoteHistoryBox.Text.Remove(QuoteHistoryBox.Text.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine))
```

But this code is necessary to be kept due to how the program works, and was wondering if there was a work around.

Here is the remove last buttons code:

```
    Private Sub Button12_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RemoveLastBtn.Click
    ' do absolutelty nothing if the box is already empty
    If QuoteHistoryBox.Lines.Count = 1 Or QuoteHistoryBox.Text = "" Then
        QuoteHistoryBox.Text = ""
        FinalQuoteBox.Text = 0
        removeOne = 0
        ' else, remove the last line of text, which would be the last item
    ElseIf removeOne = 0 Then
        ' create a place to store the last line in the texbox
        Dim lastBoxLine As String

        'get the last line in the textbox
        lastBoxLine = QuoteHistoryBox.Lines(QuoteHistoryBox.Lines.Length - 1)

        'if the last line is empt, get the second line instead
        If (lastBoxLine = String.Empty Or lastBoxLine = "") Then
            lastBoxLine = QuoteHistoryBox.Lines(QuoteHistoryBox.Lines.Length - 2)
        End If

        ' compare the gotten line with the number of strings
        ' if the last line matches this string, delete it, and then minus the number associated with this string, or plus if it is the contract string
        If lastBoxLine.Equals("+ Base 3D Printer: $799") Then
            lastNum = 799
            FinalQuoteBox.Text = Val(FinalQuoteBox.Text) - lastNum
        ElseIf lastBoxLine.Equals("+ High-end Printer: $3999") Then
            lastNum = 3999
            FinalQuoteBox.Text = Val(FinalQuoteBox.Text) - lastNum
        ElseIf lastBoxLine.Equals("+ Basic small print: $30") Then
            lastNum = 30
            FinalQuoteBox.Text = Val(FinalQuoteBox.Text) - lastNum
        ElseIf lastBoxLine.Equals("+ Basic medium print: $50") Then
            lastNum = 50
            FinalQuoteBox.Text = Val(FinalQuoteBox.Text) - lastNum
        ElseIf lastBoxLine.Equals("+ Basic large print: $110") Then
            lastNum = 110
            FinalQuoteBox.Text = Val(FinalQuoteBox.Text) - lastNum
        ElseIf lastBoxLine.Equals("+ High quality fdm print: %110") Then
            Dim currentVal As Double = Val(FinalQuoteBox.Text)
            lastNum = currentVal / 210
            lastNum = lastNum * 100
            FinalQuoteBox.Text = lastNum
        ElseIf lastBoxLine.Equals("+ Fdm print using ABS: %20") Then
            Dim currentVal As Double = Val(FinalQuoteBox.Text)
            lastNum = currentVal / 120
            lastNum = lastNum * 100
            FinalQuoteBox.Text = lastNum
        ElseIf lastBoxLine.Equals("+ High quality SLA print: %210") Then
            Dim currentVal As Double = Val(FinalQuoteBox.Text)
            lastNum = currentVal / 310
            lastNum = lastNum * 100
            FinalQuoteBox.Text = lastNum
        ElseIf lastBoxLine.Equals("+ Contract: - %15") Then
            Dim currentVal As Double = Val(FinalQuoteBox.Text)
            lastNum = currentVal / 85
            lastNum = lastNum * 100
            FinalQuoteBox.Text = lastNum
        ElseIf lastBoxLine.Equals("+ Prioritise request: $20") Then
            lastNum = 20
            FinalQuoteBox.Text = Val(FinalQuoteBox.Text) - lastNum
        End If

        ' remove box text
        QuoteHistoryBox.Text = QuoteHistoryBox.Text.Remove(QuoteHistoryBox.Text.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine))
        QuoteHistoryBox.Text = QuoteHistoryBox.Text.Remove(QuoteHistoryBox.Text.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine))
        removeOne = removeOne + 1

    Else

        ' create a place to store the last line in the texbox
        Dim lastBoxLine As String

        'get the last line in the textbox
        lastBoxLine = QuoteHistoryBox.Lines(QuoteHistoryBox.Lines.Length - 1)

        'if the last line is empt, get the second line instead
        If (lastBoxLine = String.Empty Or lastBoxLine = "") Then
            lastBoxLine = QuoteHistoryBox.Lines(QuoteHistoryBox.Lines.Length - 2)
        End If

        ' compare the gotten line with the number of strings
        ' if the last line matches this string, delete it, and then minus the number associated with this string, or plus if it is the contract string

        If lastBoxLine.Equals("+ Base 3D Printer: $799") Then
            lastNum = 799
            FinalQuoteBox.Text = Val(FinalQuoteBox.Text) - lastNum
        ElseIf lastBoxLine.Equals("+ High-end Printer: $3999") Then
            lastNum = 3999
            FinalQuoteBox.Text = Val(FinalQuoteBox.Text) - lastNum
        ElseIf lastBoxLine.Equals("+ Basic small print: $30") Then
            lastNum = 30
            FinalQuoteBox.Text = Val(FinalQuoteBox.Text) - lastNum
        ElseIf lastBoxLine.Equals("+ Basic medium print: $50") Then
            lastNum = 50
            FinalQuoteBox.Text = Val(FinalQuoteBox.Text) - lastNum
        ElseIf lastBoxLine.Equals("+ Basic large print: $110") Then
            lastNum = 110
            FinalQuoteBox.Text = Val(FinalQuoteBox.Text) - lastNum
            FinalQuoteBox.Text = Val(FinalQuoteBox.Text) - lastNum
        ElseIf lastBoxLine.Equals("+ High quality fdm print: %110") Then
            ' correctly gets the old money value before the increase
            Dim currentVal As Double = Val(FinalQuoteBox.Text)
            lastNum = currentVal / 210
            lastNum = lastNum * 100
            FinalQuoteBox.Text = lastNum
        ElseIf lastBoxLine.Equals("+ Fdm print using ABS: %20") Then
            Dim currentVal As Double = Val(FinalQuoteBox.Text)
            lastNum = currentVal / 120
            lastNum = lastNum * 100
            FinalQuoteBox.Text = lastNum
        ElseIf lastBoxLine.Equals("+ High quality SLA print: %210") Then
            Dim currentVal As Double = Val(FinalQuoteBox.Text)
            lastNum = currentVal / 310
            lastNum = lastNum * 100
            FinalQuoteBox.Text = lastNum
        ElseIf lastBoxLine.Equals("+ Contract: - %15") Then
            Dim currentVal As Double = Val(FinalQuoteBox.Text)
            lastNum = currentVal / 85
            lastNum = lastNum * 100
            FinalQuoteBox.Text = lastNum
            FinalQuoteBox.Text = Val(FinalQuoteBox.Text) + lastNum
        ElseIf lastBoxLine.Equals("+ Prioritise request: $20") Then
            lastNum = 20
            FinalQuoteBox.Text = Val(FinalQuoteBox.Text) - lastNum
        End If

        QuoteHistoryBox.Text = QuoteHistoryBox.Text.Remove(QuoteHistoryBox.Text.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine))
        removeOne = removeOne + 1

    End If

End Sub
```

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I've found the answer. I just put it in a try catch block and added:

```
Catch ex As ArgumentOutOfRangeException
        QuoteHistoryBox.Text = ""
        FinalQuoteBox.Text = 0
        removeOne = 0
    End Try
```

To catch when the line was only one item, and do a specific thing if it is in the catch block. Problem solved.